# Centralizing / abstracting SQL Server data from multiple tables / databases

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting

If one has a number of databases (due to separate application front-ends) that provide a complete picture - for example a CRM, accounting, and product database - what methods are available to centralize/abstract this data for easy reporting?

Essentially, I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically pull data from multiple databases into a central repository that is continuously updated from the three databases and which can be used for reporting?

I'm also open to alternative best practice suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into building a [Data warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse).

It is difficult to provide very specific info, since no version of SQL Server is given, but [SQL Server Data Warehouse Cribsheet](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-data-warehouse-cribsheet/) has some general information.

Answer (score 1):

you can have views that join data from all your other databases.

Or do you want replicated data on all servers?